# Insert bookmark in .pdf file for print

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have searched many solutions on what is the best way to search a `.pdf`, and if a page named spec_out is located in the `.pdf` it will insert the first bookmark before other bookmarks as Spec Out.  I'm trying to do it within the terminal of Ubuntu.  More than likely I'll make a shell script of it.  I reviewed PDFtk, pdfWriteBookmarks, LaTeX, pdfpages, and pdfmark, but I am not seeing a solid solution.  I did see someone donated some `.py` script per another thread but I haven't tried my hand at python yet.